# css not loading in codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter, base-url

I have this code

```
<link href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css” rel=”stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

which supposed to load the `style.css` from the css folder. The `echo base_url()` itself works.
I also have autoloaded the `url helper`, so i really don't see the problem here, but it still doesn't load.

Comment: Open the url given in the Source Code and give us the error here. My bets are that your .htaccess isn't correct.

Comment: Are you sure that your css folder is located in your website root?

Comment: It seems that after this " charcter i used ” this and it didn't match. So it really was a typo. Source Code view showed it.

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure that the directory is not "blocked" by the `.htaccess` file, if you are using it to remove index.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Personally I would move the css diectory into an assets directory:

```
/assets/css
/assets/js
/assets/img
```

Answer (score 2):

the default location for css files is the same level as the application i.e.,

```
/css
/application
```

Check the path as has been suggested.

Answer (score 1):

View the source of the page and click the css file link, if it 404s then check your .htaccess file and make sure that that directory is available!

Answer (score 0):

try including the relative link in the function like on the [user_guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

```
< link href = " < ? php echo base_url('css/style.css') ; ? >” rel=”stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

application/views/globals/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
or whatever your folders srtucture is!