# Images not displaying in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

My image folder of Codeigniter is in root directory as follows

```
/applications/
/system/
/images/
```

I am using following code to display the images

```
 <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/my_image.jpg'); ?>">
```

I am getting the correct location of image in HTML markup in img src, 
but not displaying the image.

Where i missed it ? Your valuable advices are highly appreciated.

Comment: may be permission issue.

Comment: could u please explain .. Iam using wamp server running in localhost

Comment: can you open that image in browser? Just copy the image src path via firebug and paste in url bar.

Comment: yes!! 404 NOT found ..

Comment: Then you have to solve it first. Do you have any htaccess in your folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css not loading in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470171/css-not-loading-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your htaccess file.Whether it has allowed images to load in the webpage.Here i'll put a working htaccess file.Try it..

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Perfect answer. You have to add your folder name where you are storing images.